# Magento register page duplicate State Dropdown

Tags: php, magento

I need to have a new drop down in the registration page like State / Province in Magento. Is there anyway to duplicate this and add in the database other values?

Thank you

```
            <div class="field">
                <label for="region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                        <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    //<![CDATA[
                        $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue', "<?php echo $this->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>");
                    //]]>
                    </script>
                    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The handling of customer (personal) data and customer addresses data is separated in Magento. On the registration page the customer should only enter the least information possible to create an account. After the customer got his account and logged in he gets the possibility to add shipping/billing addresses with proper state dropdown.

So if you are creating a state dropdown on the registration page, there is no address you could save this value to, as the customer object does not have any state field ... only the customer address object which is not yet create.

**UPDATE:**
If you desperately need a dropdown on the registration page you need to write your own module, with all the logic to save it to the database, create new addresses, etc.

**UPDATE2:**
There is a good example in the file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml` to show you how to create a state dropdown.

Comment: and what will be the solution to have two dropdowns?

Comment: Hi thank you, I know that I need a module, for that I post here, maybe someone can point me in one direction, My question was how I can make new dropdown like State / Province

Comment: no is not that file, I work in this file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml, because I enable the Persistent Checkout, and is almost the same like what you add in the UPDATE2. Maybe a good idea will be to tell me how we can add that dropdown.